# Codeigniter ckeditor add span tag

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor for codeigniter project, when i try to add span tags it's getting replaced with p tag.
Is there any way to add span tag using ckeditor?

Comment: How are you adding the span tag? We need to see your CKEditor configuration and other related code :)

Comment: What was the spam tags? I fix it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have XSS filter turned on in the config file? It removes some "illegal" tags from your POST input.
Try this